# Вызов виртуального приватного метода в классе-потомке

Tags: c++, vmt

Как-то на одном из форумов зашел разговор о "невозможности/возможности" вызова приватного метода класса-предка из объекта класса-потомка. Вопрос заинтересовал и я решил поэкспериментировать. Таки получилось:

[Онлайн исполнение](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UTyRCvuwWJJkvxkU)

```
#include <iostream>

// -------------------------------------------------------

class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
  private:
    virtual void ShowBase() {
      std::cout << "BaseShow" << std::endl;
    }
};

// -------------------------------------------------------

class Derived: public Base {
  public:
    virtual void ShowDerived() {
      std::cout << "DerivedShow" << std::endl;
    }
};

// -------------------------------------------------------

#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #define IDX 1
#else
  #define IDX 2
#endif  


int main() {
  Derived *D = new Derived();
  (*(void(*)(void*))((void**)(*(void**)D))[IDX])(D);  
  delete D;
  return 0;
}
```

Реализация - по сути является хаком.

**Вопрос**

Каковы условия того, чтобы приведенный код был нерабочим? Договоримся, что индекс (в коде сейчас это `2`) рассчитывается правильно при модификации базового класса.

**Add 1**: "Проблему" с длиной указателя исправил. Под вопросом только VC++

**Add 2**: "Проблему" с M$ VC++ исправил - там свой порядок построения VMT

Comment: Вы считаете приведённый код *рабочим*?

Comment: А может прибежать оптимизатор и выбросить классы. И все... приехали.

Comment: @alexolut , код выполняет то, что требовалось.

Comment: @Majestio код, основанный на UB не может быть рабочим. Это лишь видимость работы.

Comment: вот этот онлайн компилятор http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual выдал ошибку,  http://cpp.sh/ выдал baseShow, а http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ - выдал DerivedShow. Покрыли 3 варианта с 4.

Comment: Хакнуть можно и проще :) - в заголовочном файле Base написать `friend class Derived` :)

Comment: лучше применить паттерн "паблик Морозов". выглядит он так `#define private public`. Работает безотказно, совместим со всеми известными мне компиляторами.

Comment: С "Павликом Морозовым" - это кучерявый баян)))

Comment: @KoVadim `#define private public` - это уже инквизиция какая-то, а не Паблик Морозов! Паблик Морозов, исходя из своего названия, обязан быть дочерним классом

Comment: а как использовать этот паттерн при приватной функции? при протектед делал и не раз)

Comment: @pavel никак. Отец должен доверять сыну, чтобы тот мог его выдать!

Comment: (*(void(*)(void*))((void**)(*(void**)D))[2])(D); - тёмная магия, не боитесь призвать демона таким вызовом?

Comment: Да не магия совсем - а вызов 3-го метода из первой VMT :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как и любой хак, ваш хак работает на конкретном компиляторе и конкретной платформе.

Самый простой способ поломать код - перейти на архитектуру x64 в режиме LLP64 (например, используя компилятор VC++), где размер типа long не совпадает с размером указателя.

Впрочем, на VC++, все сломается даже на x86, потому что формат таблицы виртуальных функций отличается.

А ведь есть и более экзотические платформы...

Comment: На x64 работает прекрасно. Но за ответ - спасибо.

Comment: @Majestio ...но только на нижних адресах :-) Попробуйте указать базу для загрузки на пятом гигабайте

Comment: На VC++ написало "*DerivedShow*" :)

Comment: Увы, данного компилятора у меня нет - спасибо за проверку).

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, согласно http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types - под *nix используется модель данных `LP64 или 4/8/8 (int — 32 бита, long и указатель — 64 бита) `. Там работать будет.

Comment: @Majestio это особенность конкретной реализации

Comment: Конечно, согласен.

Comment: Немного изменил код

Comment: Теперь работает везде)

Comment: @Majestio на микроконтроллерах проверьте :-)

Comment: Проверил только факт успешной компиляции на ARM64, MIPS/MIPS64, PowerPC, x86_64 ICC :-)

Answer (score 10):

Не знаю, ограничена ли была ваша дискуссия "на одном из форумов" только темой VMT-хаков, но тем не менее замечу, что при желании можно безо всяких хаков (и не модифицируя определение "вскрываемого" класса) вызвать любой приватный метод

```
#include <iostream>

class Private {
  void private_func() { std::cout << "Pwned!" << std::endl; }
};

using PTR = void (Private::*)();
PTR ptr;

template <PTR ptr> struct Exploit {                
  static struct D { D() { ::ptr = ptr; } } d;
};

template <PTR ptr> typename Exploit<ptr>::D Exploit<ptr>::d;

template struct Exploit<&Private::private_func>;

int main() {
  (Private().*ptr)();
}
```

Разумеется, смысла в таких приемах мало. Если уж к чему-то позарез нужен доступ, то не было смысла делать его приватным.

P.S. Вот уж чего этот метод не может сделать, так вызвать приватный виртуальный метод предка для объекта-потомка, если в потомке этот метод перекрыт. С++ не предоставляет средств подавления виртуальности вызова при вызове через указатель на метод.

Comment: Код интересный, но нет наследования.

Comment: @Majestio: Это замечание из разряда "но нет цикла `for`". Хотите наследование - добавьте наследование. Кто ж вам мешает? Оно ведь тут ни на что не влияет. Еще раз: этот метод позволяет вам доступиться к приватному члену *любого* класса. Базового/не базового, с наследованием/без наследования... Любого.

Comment: Пробовал - компилятор на `ideone.com` ругается. Если не сложно - поправьте свой код, чтобы было наследование.

Comment: Не понимаю смысла.. Но пжлст: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/949fb88949fc5ec0

Comment: Спасибо, норм )