# Управление доступом

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, инкапсуляция

Как еще можно обойти защищенность полей в ооп? кроме дружественных функций

Comment: Заменить `private` на `public` :)

Answer (score 11):

Если говорить действительно о "взломах защиты", т.е. о способах, которые не требуют кооперации со стороны "взламываемого" класса (т.е. не опираются на изначально заложенные в класс возможности, типа "друзей", методов, возвращающих указатели на члены и т.п.), то одна из малоизвестных "дыр", созданных в языке намеренно - это разрешение для *явного инстанциирования* шаблона игнорировать ограничения доступа.

В следующем примере мы, не используя никаких "хаков", "друзей" или методов самого класса, обходим защиту доступа к private методу

```
#include <iostream>

class Private {
  void private_func() { std::cout << "Pwned!" << std::endl; }
};

using PTR = void (Private::*)();
PTR ptr;

template <PTR ptr> struct Exploit {                
  static inline struct D { D() { ::ptr = ptr; } } d;
};

template struct Exploit<&Private::private_func>;

int main() {
  (Private().*ptr)();
}
```

Ключевой момент этой возможности - в разрешении (данном нам разделом 14.7.2/12 стандарта языка) делать

```
template struct Exploit<&Private::private_func>;
```

несмотря на то, что функция `Private::private_func` является private.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы уже писали где-то об этом.

Comment: @alexolut: Да, было. Щас... Вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656525/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B5/656542 Здесь это более по теме, чем там :)

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, то в VC++ это "пофиксили".

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае? Или в каких-то конкретных?

Читерство типа

```
#define private public
```

считаем недостойным настоящего программиста? :) Копирование описания класса из заголовочного файла с добавлением в него, например, дружественной функции - тоже?

Есть вариант с созданием своего класса с аналогичным размещением членов в памяти и `reinterpret_cast` указателя на один объект в указатель на свой - незаконно, UB, но... обычно вполне прокатывает :)

Например, через указатель - если тот же друг создаст указатель на что-то закрытое и вернет его, типа

```
class X
{  
private: int y;

friend int* z(X&x) { return &x.y; };

...

int * p = z(x);
*p = 5;
```

Или это не годится, хотя дружественная функция используется опосредованно?

Вот вариант со специализацией шаблонной функции. Допустим, есть некий класс.

```
class X
{
public:
    template<typename T>
        void f(const T& t)
    { /* ... */ }
private:
    int p;
};
```

Специализируем эту функцию...

```
namespace {
    struct Y{};
}

template<>
void X::f(const Y&)
{
    p = 5;
}
```

и все. Ловкость рук и никакого мошенничества...