# C++ ООП.Доступ к private

Tags: c++, c++17

Есть ли возможность в C++ достать объект из private без наследования?

```
class Table{
public:
    void start();

    bool check_figure(int x, int y) const;

    bool check_move(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_king(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_queen(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_elephant(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_horse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_tower(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_pawn(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    bool check_move_pre(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);


    void move(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Figures trans = Figures::none);
    void reverse_motion();

    Figure get(int i, int j) const { return desk[j][i];}

    int get_number_move() const { return number_move;}

    void display_position();

    Table(){start();}

    bool attack(int x, int y, FigColor col_attack) const;

    One_Move past_moves(unsigned int i) const {return all_moves[all_moves.size() - i];}

    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves(FigColor move_col);
    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves_king(int x, int y);       //улучшить
    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves_queen(int x, int y);      //улучшить
    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves_elephant(int x, int y);   //улучшить
    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves_horse(int x, int y);      //улучшить
    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves_tower(int x, int y);      //улучшить
    vector <One_Motion> pos_moves_pawn(int x, int y);       //улучшить

    Situation desk_situation();
private:
    Figure desk[n_cells][n_cells] = {};
    int number_move = 0;

    vector<One_Move> all_moves;

    //нет перешагивания через фигуру (не нужно для коня)
    bool no_step_over(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) const;

    King_tower white_king;
    King_tower black_king;

    bool shah(FigColor) const;
};
```

Comment: Очень надеюсь что нет, иначе это проблема в дизайне языка.

Comment: Покажите ваш класс?

Comment: А что, с наследованием вы уже смогли?

Comment: Да , я думаю , тут либо косвенно доставать по ссылке , либо объявить в этом классе дружественную функцию

Comment: Шаблонный трюк с честным и законным способом "взлома" приватности я уже приводил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771601/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC Но вряд ли это то, что вам нужно

Comment: И, что именно вы хотите "достать из private" в этом классе?

Comment: Очень бы хотелось, чтобы автор уточнил, что он подразумевает под "доступом к private". Например, я могу понять это как доступ через открытый getter, и тогда ответ будет простым. И, самое главное, узнать конечную цель автора, может быть этой цели можно достигнуть "легальными" методами

Answer (score 5):

> достать объект из private без наследования

Из наследника Вы до `private` не достучитесь, максимум до `protected`. Используйте [дружественные функции или классы](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/5.5.php) или вложенные классы (если используете C++ 11 или выше).

Во всех остальных случаях только через октрытые геттеры или сеттеры.

Comment: Спасибо , большое

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендовал бы книгу Г. Саттера "[Новые сложные задачи на С++](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0823-X.html)" - в ней в задаче 16 рассматриваются как раз варианты достучаться до этого кода.

Первый основан на указателе - на том, что код, имеющий доступ к члену, может передать этот доступ любому другому коду, передав указатель на этот член.

Второй - с применением шаблонов. Любой шаблон члена может быть специализирован для любого типа. Специализируя его для некоторого уникального типа (в безымянном пространстве имен), вы создаете собственную функцию-член, а член класса имеет доступ ко всем частям класса...

Однако - эти методы требуют *изменения* объявления класса, т.е. вмешательства в заголовочный файл, а тогда уж проще просто убрать слово `private` :)

P.S. Обнаружил, что [уже писал на эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771604/195342)...

Comment: > Обнаружил, что уже писал на эту тему... 
Сложно найти тему, на которую Вы еще не писали :)