# Доступ одного класса к protected полям другого класса с общим предком

Tags: c++

Я делаю некую имитацию UI. Проблема в том, что при добавлении элемента в layout, он подгоняет позицию элемента под позицию других элементов и следовательно мне нужен доступ к этой переменной(_position). Однако компилятор не разрешает это сделать. Так как все элементы имеют одинакового предка, то по идее должен быть способ как-то обмануть компилятор. Изменять область видимости на public не очень хочется, так как нарушается инкапсуляция.

```
class UIObject{
protected:
    Rect _position;
...
}

class Text : public UIObject
{
...
}

class Layout : public UIObject
{
...
public:
   void add_object(UIObject* object){
       добавление в коллекцию
       ...
       изменение _position у object
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, это странная идея - обманывать компилятор....

Comment: доступа тут нет, так как вы пытаетесь получить доступ к полю объекта, который не является подобъектом данного объекта. Наследование от UIObject не позволяет получать доступ к protected полям других объектов. Так что делайте public геттер

Comment: При public наследовании вы же и так получаете доступ к public и protected родительского класса. Разве нет?

Comment: видимо нужно делать UIObject другом Layout.

Comment: @e.n.shirokov только к protected экземпляра родительского класса, который является подобъектом этого объекта, то бишь через this

Comment: я попытался собрать приведенный в вопросе код, что бы он "не компилировался", но пока не получается.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1043698/195342 - и еще вот этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771601/195342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обмануть компилятор можно через указатель-на-член. Но лучше найти какое-то нормальное решение, без подобных выкрутасов.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  protected:
    int x = 42;
};

struct B : A
{
    void foo(A *a)
    {
        // Не работает:
        // std::cout << a->x << '\n';

        // Вместо `auto` можно использовать `int A::*`.
        auto member = &B::x;
        std::cout << a->*member << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: Вы просто волшебник. Я всё ещё не понимаю как это работает. Не могли бы объяснить как? И не знаете ли вы такого же трюка с виртуальными функциями?

Comment: @КириллЧуркин Даже не знаю, что именно тут объяснить. `&B::x` возвращает указатель-на-член на `x`, типа `int A::*` (как ни странно не `int B::*`, потому что `x` унаследован из `A`; хотя при этом `&A::x` не компилируется из-за `protected`).

Comment: С виртуальными функциями это тоже должно работать. Пишете все точно так же, только вместо `a->*member` делаете `(a->*member)(параметры)`.

Comment: Но почему изменяется адрес, и вообще почему компилятор позволяет поставить левую переменную вместо имени поля?
С виртуальными функциями так не получается

Comment: @КириллЧуркин Получается: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vqGrGz А, так вы вообще про указатели-на-члены не слышали? Там слишком много, чтобы в комментах объяснять, лучше погуглите (можно на англ. - "pointers to members") или в какой-нибудь книге по плюсам посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо, я почитал, это довольно неочевидная тема.
По поводу виртуальных функций, [ссылка](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WcfsnY) при переопределении начинается беда

Comment: @КириллЧуркин Хмм, действительно. Можно так: `auto member = (void (A::*)(int))&B::foo;`.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случаи объект `Layout` не является потомком объекта `object`, поэтому его функция_член не может пользоваться  защищенным членом `object`. Но его функция_член может пользоваться защищенным и закрытым членом своего класса, поэтому, если приводить указатель к указателю на `Layout`, то можно получать доступ:

```
void add_object(UIObject* object) {
   static_cast<Layout*>(object)->_position = /*...*/;
}
```

Comment: А что если alignment собьётся? Ведь сюда может прийти любой наследник UIObject. И тогда для этого лучше использовать reinterpret_cast, нет?

Comment: вот reinterpret_cast точно не нужен. тут скорее dynamic_cast нужен.

Comment: @КириллЧуркин `reinterpret_cast` тоже не подойдет, потому что у класса может быть больше одного родителя (и адрес всех непустых родителей кроме первого будет отличаться от адреса потомка).

Comment: @KoVadim, тип не полиморфный, чтобы применить dynamic_cast

Comment: @Кирилл Чуркин, а какая разница какой наследник? Они всеравно статически связаны

Answer (score 0):

Почитав немного сайтов на данную тематику, я понял, что такой вопрос встречается довольно часто. Поэтому я решил немного резюмировать всю информацию. Доступ к protected членам запрещён документацией. Но это можно обойти, используя "pointers to members". Большое спасибо HolyBlackCat за оказанную помощь.
Ниже я оставлю свой код(здесь так же есть использование и виртуальных функций, получилось добраться только так (компилятор msvc)).

```
class UIObject {
protected:
    Rectangle _position;
protected:
    virtual void update_position() {}
}

class Layout :
    public UIObject
{
protected:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UIObject>> _objects;
}

class HorizontalLayout :
    public Layout
{
private:
    virtual void update_position() override {
        bool first_object_flag = true;
        decltype(auto) object_position = &HorizontalLayout::_position;
        _position.width = 0;
        for (auto&& object : _objects) {
            if (first_object_flag) {
                (*object.*object_position).x = _position.x;
                _position.width += (*object.*object_position).width;
                first_object_flag = false;
            }
            else {
                (*object.*object_position).x = _position.x + _position.width + 1;
                _position.width += ((*object.*object_position).width + 1);
            }
            (*object.*object_position).y = (_position.y * 2 + _position.height - 1) / 2 - object->height() / 2;
            decltype(auto) object_update_positiion = &HorizontalLayout::UIObject::update_position;
            ((*object).*object_update_positiion)();

        }
public:
    template<class _UIObject, class... Args>
    _UIObject& add_object(Args&&... args) {
        _objects.emplace_back(std::make_unique<_UIObject>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        decltype(auto) object = *_objects.back();
        decltype(auto) object_position = &HorizontalLayout::_position;
        if (_objects.size() == 1) {
            (object.*object_position).x = _position.x;
            _position.width += (object.*object_position).width;
        }
        else {
            (object.*object_position).x = _position.x + _position.width + 1;
            _position.width += ((object.*object_position).width + 1);
        }
        if(object.height() > _position.height){
            _position.height = object.height();
            this->update_position();
        }
        (object.*object_position).y = (_position.y*2 + _position.height - 1) / 2 - object.height() / 2;
        return static_cast<_UIObject&>(object);
    }
};
```

Comment: Если спецификатор доступа не позволяет обращаться к какой-либо сущности, то это говорит либо о том, что вы действительно пытаетесь обратится к чему-то, к чему не должны обращаться, либо о том, что иерархия классов или спецификатор доступа составлены некорректно. Но никогда о том, что это ограничение надо пытаться как-то обходить.

Comment: @user7860670 Данная ситуация говорит лишь о том, что я не хочу писать длинный столбец из forward declaration и объявлять ещё такой же столбец классов-друзей, и упаси меня боже в таком случае забыть заинклюдить хоть один файл с реализацией. Такой подход видимо для вас намного удобнее. Есть ещё один способ - сеттеры, но я считаю, что как только они появляются в методах, то можно сразу менять доступ на public, ибо смысла уже не очень от них. Я хотел не нарушать инкапсуляцию, при этом дав лишь некоторым классам власть менять данные

Comment: "Я хотел не нарушать инкапсуляцию" - ну а зачем тогда нарушаете?